# APL: how to search for a value's index in a matrix

Tags: matrix, vector, indexing, parallel-processing, apl

In APL, matrices and vectors are used to hold data. I was wondering if there was a way to search within a matrix for a given value, and have that values index returned. For example, say I have the following 2-dimensional matrices:

`VALUES ← 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11...` all the way up to 36

`KINDS ←  0 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 ...` filled with 0's the rest of the way to 36 length.

If I laminated these two matrices with

```
kinds,[.5] values
```

so that they are laminated one on top of the other

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10...
0 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 ....
```

is there a functionally easy way to search for the index of the 2 value in the "second row" of the newly laminated matrix? eg. the column containing

```
4
2
```

and return that matrix index?

Answer (score 2):

The value **2** also appears in row 1 of your newly laminated matrix (nlm), and as you stated, you really do not want to search the whole matrix, but only the second row. So, since you're only searching within a given row,  getting the column index in that row gives you the complete answer:

```
    row←2
    ⎕←col←nlm[row;]⍳2
4
    nlm[;col]  ⍝ values in matched column
4 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P8zRJ9Q1@FHbhEe9m43NuLw9/VxAPGOzR71bDBQedbcogIWiTRQsYoHiRgrGXHk5uUAWRKNOtJ5pLFiFgsKj3rkKeanlOZUKOYm5mXmJJakpCrmJJUWZFVxcRfnlYN0gNcWpiUXJGQolGZnFCkBxrkd9U4Fyyfk5QBJodjRQzDoW6Bwjrv//AQ)

Comment: @z.rubi:  can you pls. accept the answer, so that the question is no longer shown as "open" (just tick the check-mark next to the reply).